# Large gaps between CardView items when adding Toolbar to activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-cardview

I have an activity which displays the results of searching for a musician, when i add my custom toolbar to the XML it displays these large bars between each CardView element. I'm unsure of what is causing this as when i remove the toolbar, it looks fine.

**XML:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorSplash"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/artistName"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/artistImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />


    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Activity:**

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<Artist> artistList;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    List<searchItem> results = new ArrayList<>();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_results_activity);
    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    artistList = handleIntent(getIntent());
    for(int i=0; i< artistList.size();i++)
    {
        String name = artistList.get(i).getName();
        String image = artistList.get(i).getImageURL(ImageSize.LARGE);
        searchItem item = new searchItem(name, image);
        results.add(item);
    }



    adapter = new searchItemAdapter(results, getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}



@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    handleIntent(intent);
}

private List<Artist> handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        String test = query;
        try {
            artistList = new searching2().execute(query).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return artistList;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater mMenuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    mMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    SearchView search = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch));

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    search.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, SearchResultsActivity.class)));
    search.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    //popup for about
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_about_us){
        PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(this);
        View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.about_popup, null);
        popup.setContentView(layout);
        popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popup.setFocusable(true);
        popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
    }
    //go to sign in page
    else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_sign_in){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
class searching2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Artist>>
{

@Override
protected List<Artist> doInBackground(String...query)
{
    String test2 = query[0];
    Caller.getInstance().setUserAgent("tst");
    List<Artist> test = new ArrayList<Artist>(Artist.search(test2, "5bd9e71b5242c6eb80f7be611d05ac34"));
    return test;
}
}
```

**How it looks with toolbar:**

[image]

**How it looks without the toolbar**

[image]

Comment: Seems like you're using the `search_results_activity` layout for the `RecyclerView` items in your `searchItemAdapter`. If so, that's not what you want to do. You need to create a separate layout for your items, and your `CardView` would go in that.

Comment: Recyclerview and Cardview(i.e. item_view ) are in single xml?

Comment: CardLayout is your Row items? which is in Different XML.

Comment: @MikeM. I'm not 100% sure i understand what you mean, i moved the recyclerView to another layout and included that in the original layout but the problem persist.

Comment: @ArnoldBrown please refer to the comment reply to the first comment, if this is what you mean't.

Comment: @farhana Cardlayout?

Comment: No, leave the `RecyclerView` where it's at. Look in your `searchItemAdapter`, in the `onCreateViewHolder()` method. Which layout are you inflating there? It seems like it's `search_results_activity`, which you don't want. You want to create a separate layout for your items that you inflate there, then move the `CardView` to that new, separate layout.

Comment: Your main xml with Toolbar should contain Recyclerview and the xml you used in adapter class to set item row should contain the cardview as seperate xml which contain only cardview and its child and not a Toolbar and Recyclerview.

Comment: @Kannei it means XML code of Row item and main layout XML are posted together, is CardLayout row item class?

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you for the explanation, it worked perfectly.

Comment: @ArnoldBrown I got it to work, thank you!